# implementing advertisement directive in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a newbie angular. I am working with an angular application. My client requirement is to add an advertisement in some pages. I have the data like position for advertisement, advertisement image etc. I would like to implement this functionality as creating an angular directive. So I can call this directive as tag in my pages. So can anyone tell how to write this directive?
Please see the code below:

```
zentieraDirectives.directive('advertisement',function($http,$rootScope){
$http.post($rootScope.STATIC_URL + 'admins/getadvertisement').success(function(response){
     console.log("success advertisement");

            return {
template: 'Name: <img src="https://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-small.png" /> <span ng-click="closeAdvertisement()">X</span>'


};
}) .error(function(err){
            console.log("Error"+err);
        });

});
```

When I check on console, I got "success advertisement", but not returned the template. I checked this on another way

```
app.directive('advertisement', function() {


return {
template: 'Name: {{advertisement}} <img src="https://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-small.png" /> <span ng-click="closeAdvertisement()">X</span>'


 };

});
```

My need is that, on the success of api call to node, I  have to return the template. My view page is

```
<h1>advertisement</h1>
 <advertisement ng-show="advertisementShow"></advertisement>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.  You need to show some effort and research.  Where is your code?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry. I have written the code. Can u plz check my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.directive('navBannerTop', ['NavBannerServiceTop','$rootScope', function (nbs,$window) {

 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    //scope: true,
    scope: {},

   template:' <div><a href= "{{banner_link}}"  target="_blank"> <img ng-src="{{zentieraUrl}}/assets/images/adBanner/{{banner_pic_url}}"></a></div>',
    link: function ($scope,$element,$attr,$rootScope) {
          var imagePosition=$attr.imageposition;
          nbs.getImage(imagePosition).then(function(result){
              $scope.banner_pic_url = result.data.banner;
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Finally I have solved the problem. First I create a directive. In that directive, I returned a template. The directive uses a service too.

```
app.service('NavBannerServiceTop', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q,$rootScope) {
var deferred = $q.defer();
var service = {};
service.getImage = function (imagePosition) {
        var params={
        position:imagePosition
    };
    $http.post(Config.STATIC_URL + 'users/getadvertisement',params).success(function (data) {
         var adImage=data.data.banner;
         var advlink=data.data.advlink;
          deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function () {
         deferred.reject('some error');
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
return service;
}]);
```

In the service, I take the data from server, ie the image url.This image url is passed to directive. In the view side I call the directive as a custom tag.

Answer (score -1):

I create a little example of this

http://embed.plnkr.co/HD0KGabjWoq7bnwGaN5E/

I create a directive for the advertisement, and the "X" is for close this.

The functionality is in the controller (this not recomend but is for example).
I hope solve your doubt

Comment: In the example, I only explain how function the directive, the specific functionality you have to code-write you

Comment: Your code really helps me. But i need some more extension.can u plz ceck my updated question?